# I have a JSON file with data property which contains objects that contain information about champions. How to get champion with specific KEY property?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a huge static JSON file that contains all champions in a certain game and some information about them. Currently, I need to figure out how to find the champion object whose "key" property is 266. Sadly I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to get that object. I assume I have to loop through the objects, however, usually when I loop through something, it's an array but this is not the case.

I've put a simplified example of the json structure below. I have an integer 266 and now I need to somehow access the object with "key": "266" which would be Aatrox. Any clues on how would I do that?

```
"data": {
    "Aatrox": {
        "version": "8.19.1",
        "id": "Aatrox",
        "key": "266",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade"
    },
    "Ahri": {
        "version": "8.19.1",
        "id": "Ahri",
        "key": "103",
        "name": "Ahri",
        "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is performance important?

Comment: Well I'm just making the project in order to learn so it's not like this is a real project but if I am to learn something, it's better to do it right, right?

Comment: Having a large JSON file is probably a bad start for most things already ;) But when that is what you want or have to work with, there are tools that can have a great impact on performance. For example, instead of reading the whole file, parsing everything, then looping over the data, you could use a streaming JSON parser. For example http://oboejs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find

- Get the entries from data key using `Object.entries`
- Find value whose key property is equal to our desired key using `find`

```js
let obj = {"data": {"Aatrox": {"version": "8.19.1","id": "Aatrox","key": "266","name": "Aatrox","title": "the Darkin Blade"},"Ahri": {"version": "8.19.1","id": "Ahri","key": "103","name": "Ahri","title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"}}}

let findByKey = (matchKey) => Object.entries(obj.data).find(([key,value]) => value.key === matchKey)

console.log(findByKey('266'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function you can use to search for any key and value:

```js
const obj = {"data": {"Aatrox": {"version": "8.19.1","id": "Aatrox","key": "266","name": "Aatrox","title": "the Darkin Blade"},"Ahri": {"version": "8.19.1","id": "Ahri","key": "103","name": "Ahri","title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"}}}

const searchKeyValue = {key:"key", value:"266"}
const search = data => skv => Object.entries(data).filter(([key,value])=>value[skv.key]===skv.value)

console.log(search(obj.data)(searchKeyValue))
```

So you can find via e.g. `searchKeyValue = {key:"id", value:"Ahri"}` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JSONPath i.e.

```
$..data[?(@.key==266)]
```

Assuming :

```
{"data": {
    "Aatrox": {
        "version": "8.19.1",
        "id": "Aatrox",
        "key": "266",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade"
    },
    "Ahri": {
        "version": "8.19.1",
        "id": "Ahri",
        "key": "103",
        "name": "Ahri",
        "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"
    }
}
}
```